# Get the parameters of extended method in extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-methods

Let's say I have method:

```
public int Method(string param1, string param2)
{
     return 0;
}
```

And I have extension method

```
public static int Extend(this int mhd, string param1, string param2)
{
     return mhd;
}
```

And I would call it like

```
int N = Method("param1","param2").Extend("param1","param2");
```

But with this I had to define parameters two times. I wonder Is there way to get extend methods paramters like this:

```
public static int Extend(this int mhd)
{
     var params = this.Parameters;
     return mhd;
}
```

Comment: The direct answer is no, because the extension method does not know about how its parameter was obtained. For example, you can invoke `5.Extend("param1","param2")`. Maybe someone can help if you explain your goal at a higher-level.

Comment: `public int Method(string first param, string second param2)` - does this compile?

Comment: :) I did not see the spaces between those. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

> But with this I had to define parameters two times. I wonder Is there way to get extend methods paramters like this:

No. The 1st parameter of an extension method is always the Type the methods is for. This parameter is needed in the *declaration*, so if want to pass in anything you must declare that 2nd parameter.

---

Why not put all the code into a single method?

---

Can you invert the method dependencies? In other words something like this:

```
int N = 0.Extend(Method("param1","param2"));
```

---

Or, something like this:

```
public int Method ( int mhd, string one, string two ) {
   // do stuff...

  return mhd.Extend ( one, two );
}
```